# having issue using and/or in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having an issue thinking how to write the query i need.
I'll give you an example of what i'm trying to do..

SELECT * FROM table WHERE clause1=10 AND clause2=20 AND clause3=30||40

I need to select entries where clause1 must be exactly 10 and clause2 must be exactly 20, but clause3 can be 30 or 40 but have to be exactly 30 or exactly 40.

so it would select the entry if it were 10,20,30 or 10,20,40

SELECT * FROM table WHERE clause1=10 AND clause2=20 AND clause3=30 OR clause3=40 is incorrect though isn't it.

The numbers and clauses are only for example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got to use parentheses 'round your last condition and use two times `clause3=`:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE clause1=10 AND clause2=20 AND (clause3=30 || clause3=40)
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE clause1=10 AND clause2=20 AND clause3 IN (30, 40)
```

**Note**

I would recommend to use the operator `OR` instead of `||`, because in other SQL dialects (i.e. Oracle, Postgres) `||` is the concatenation operator. OR is standard SQL. So the first statement would better be written:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE clause1=10 AND clause2=20 AND (clause3=30 OR clause3=40)
```

**Explanation**

The operator `AND` has got higher precedence than `OR`. Without parentheses the expression the following two statements would be evaluated the same

```
     SELECT * FROM table WHERE clause1=10 AND clause2=20 AND clause3=30 OR clause3=40
     SELECT * FROM table WHERE (clause1=10 AND clause2=20 AND clause3=30) OR clause3=40
```

and that is not what you want. So either put parentheses around your OR expressions or use the simpler IN().

Answer (score 2):

Use IN.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE clause1=10 AND clause2=20 AND
clause3 in (30,40)
```